# How to fetch only first four rows of a google spreadsheet that contains more than 80K rows and more than 7 columns in GAE (using Java)

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

I have a use case and trying to fetch only first four rows of a google spreadsheet which has been published publicly and display it on a webpage.

For a spreadsheet having few 1000's of rows, there is no problem. But for spreadsheet above 80K rows are always giving timeout exception.

I had referred this link as I found it was similar to my concern:

[Unable to complete the HTTP request when using SpreadSheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099780/unable-to-complete-the-http-request-when-using-spreadsheet-api)

and have used timeout and retry timeouts, but it seems to go in an infinite loop.

I am using "ListFeed". Is it possible that because the ListFeed loads the whole spreadsheet, the application is taking more time to load?

Is there any alternative solution as I need to fetch only the first 4 - 5 rows and not the whole spreadsheet into my web application?

Please suggest and advise.

Following is the piece of code:

1. Timeout and retry:

   ```
   ListFeed lf = null;
   while (timeoutflag != 1) {
       try {
           lf = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);
           timeoutflag = 1;
       } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           timeoutinc += 2;
           service.setConnectTimeout(timeoutinc * 3000);
           service.setReadTimeout(timeoutinc * 3000);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Fetching rows:

   ```
   for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
       ListEntry le = lf.getEntries().get(k);
       CustomElementCollection cec = le.getCustomElements();
       for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
           resp.getWriter().println("<td>");
           resp.getWriter().println(cec.getValue(colname[j]));
           resp.getWriter().println("</td>");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem has been identified. The problem was because of the use of list feeds, in my code, the List Feed used to connect to the spreadsheet and required much time and memory to store all the spreadsheet in the variable:

```
 lf = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class); //Thus there used to be connection sometimes and also memory overflow exceptions in case of larger spreadsheets.
```

The solution was to use the Cell Based Feeds. I needed to fetch only a few rows, no matter how large the spreadsheet is, therefore, using cell-based feeds you can pass the parameters to the spreadsheet url and can fetch only a specific amount of rows and columns.

You can refer [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#work_with_cell-based_feeds) documentation on List and Cell Based Feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a code example could always help everyone to understand the problem better.

Im not sure what request you actually make to the sheets API, but have you tried specifying the range of the cells you need when reading the document?
You can refer to [this page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values) if you are not sure on how to do so.

Forgot to mention -- using this method you can read chunks of the document each time, process it, and fetch the next chunk of rows(if the document contains too many rows).

Comment: Thanks, The reference link was helpful. I have edited the question by adding the piece of source code. Please advise on the same.